# All in one piece, we mend holes in your socks

Tags: riddle, wordplay

All in one piece, we mend holes in your socks.

Minus a head, we're yours, skewed.

Minus a tail, we hold drinks on the rocks.

Minus another, we're you.

Minus our next head, we're nothing but us.

Minus our last tail, we're twice what you're just.

What are we?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you might be

> Sewers

All in one piece, we mend holes in your socks.

> Sewers = people who sew

Minus a head, we're yours, skewed.

> Ewers = sounds like yours

Minus a tail, we hold drinks on the rocks.

> Ewer = an open vessel with a handle and a spout for pouring

Minus another, we're you.

> Ewe = sounds like you

Minus our next head, we're nothing but us.

> We

Minus our last tail, we're twice what you're just.

> W = "double u"